# Trouble with created database returning null values for queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created a database to keep track of congressmen in two different states. I used MySQL Workbench's ER diagram GUI to create it, and to also insert values into each column. I spent hours inserting values into each table I created, and afterwards, I used the forward engineer option to convert the ER Diagram into a SQL script. Now when I want to perform queries on my database, it returns null values in each column. How is this possible? I was able to insert values into the ER diagram, and also see the data that I stored in it, but now when I perform a query on the database, it returns null values. Please help!

I've already tried Synchronizing the model, but it still gave me null values after I performed a query.

[inserted values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPwaW.png)

Here are my inserted values

Here is what happens after I perform a query

[query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAxVl.png)

Comment: Firstly, are you sure you’re connecting to the *same* database? You’re always better to create an SQL script for inserts, that way you only ever have to write it once, but you can rerun it many times (eg when you accidentally destroy you data). Try to create and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes I am sure. And I assumed that the the inserts tab of the ER Diagram would allow me to insert data. So what is its purpose if it's not going to actually store the data in the database?

Comment: I also provided screen shots as well.

Comment: Your question is not about “programming” per se, so I’m going to leave is closed for now. I’m not familiar with the tool, but may find there is a “commit” button that actually persists the data from the tool to the database. I would learn how to execute a script, then write a script to insert the data. Also, following agile principles could save to pain: try to insert 1 row first, get that working, then insert them all.